# How to make a file which when exectued will install multiple packages in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation

I want to make a file which when executed would install all the packages listed inside it like `pip install numpy`,
`pip install pandas` and others.

How is this done? please guide me to appropriate resources for learning. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
```

followed by `chmod 0755 scriptname`. The "proper" way to  do it may be to use a meta-package. See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) for details.